# How to dump mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I want to dump mysql database only the tables which have data, Can u please give me your suggestion. this is more helpful

Thanks & Regards,
Vara Kumar.PJD

Comment: If the tables does not contain data, it will not add much to the backup size. Why do you want to skip empty tables?

Comment: there are many tables,i dont want to execute empty tables queries during imports of dumped db. it will cause data lose problem.

Comment: My requirement is drop tables and insert data into those tables from dumped database file. that file contains tables those has data and create, add-drop statements .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [--ignore-table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table) option, but you have to find out which tables are empty first as this is not directly possible with mysqldump.  So you could do

```
mysqldump -u username -p database --ignore-table=database.table1 --ignore-table=database.table2 > database.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mysqldump <database options> table1 table2 table3 ...
```

Comment: there are many tables, it hard to write each one. is there any option that can dump table with data as well create , add-drop statements

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqldump` ([documentation located here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)). If you do not specify tables it assumes all tables. You can also explicitly choose tables to copy or to ignore. You can tell it to create drop statements before your create statements. If you have **mysql 5.1.2** then you can tell it to copy routines.

Answer (score 0):

When you are dumping all database. Obviously it is having large data. So you can prefer below for better:

**Creating Backup:**

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p[password]--single-transaction --quick --all-databases | gzip > alldb.sql.gz
```

**If error**

-- Warning: Skipping the data of table mysql.event. Specify the --events option explicitly.

Use:

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p --events --single-transaction --quick --all-databases | gzip > alldb.sql.gz
```

**Restoring Backup:**

```
gunzip < alldb.sql.gz | mysql -u [user] -p[password]
```

Hope it will help :)