# How can I get download .sql file from a website

Tags: sql, ftp, filezilla

I have been given an assignment to fix the bugs in a website.

They give me the username and password to access the file in the hosting.

I'm using FileZilla and got all the source but the database `.sql` file is nowhere to be found

Any idea where the `.sql` went and how do I get it from the website using FileZilla?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to dump your database to `.sql` file first. Only then you can download it.

Assuming MySQL, see [How to dump mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3725077/850848)

If you have phpMyAdmin (or a similar tool) available, you can dump and download the `.sql` file at once from the web interface directly.

Comment: how can I download it if I dumped it? using MySQL Workbench 8.0.15 , can't find it..