# export saved MySQL query with database?

Tags: mysql

I need to export my database, however when I done so and tested it by importing it again in do a different MySQL instance all my bookmarked queries were gone.

How do I export them with the database, so other people can run them by importing the database?

Is there another way?
I could just export each query as a table and have it as separate to the data base

Comment: You mean `dump database` or `export query result`? related questions:[dump db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725077/how-to-dump-mysql-database)  and  [export query result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295228/exporting-results-of-a-mysql-query-to-excel)

Comment: I can export the query results no issue, what I want to do is just export the single database with the bookmarked queries.

Comment: You mean using browser to share queries on tables with others? I don't think this is a good practice. Try write a simple script of the queries on the tables would be more convenient.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 1):

Bookmarked queries have nothing to do with the database. It's a feature of the client. For example that standard linux mysql CLI saves all executed querys to a file name .mysql_history. Like wise whatever client it is that you are using will have a place where this queries are saved, you just need to find it.